# Google Analytics single page application hitType pageview not working?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, pageviews

I made the caching of my web app much more aggressive and essentially made it a single page web app.

Even though I thought I implemented Google Analytics correctly according to [the](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages) [documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications), I am getting lots of "not set" pages. So I am guessing something is wrong with my code.

Here's how I believe I send a pageview:

```
         ga('send', {
           hitType: 'pageview',
           page: pagePath
         });
```

Where `pagePath`contains a synthetic page address.

What is wrong about this?

Comment: There's technically nothing wrong with that code. How exactly are you sending the pv? You say that that's how you believe you are doing it, so doesn't sound like you are sure yourself. You will need to show the exact code.

Comment: Here is something that it don't make sense,what i see the code is working properly and somewhere the pagePath vas is undefined, can you share how you built this var?. Because if the commands fails the hit will not reach the tool and you must have no pageview (make sense)?, not undefined one. So the pagePath is the parameter broken. I used the same come with document.location.pathName as test and works all the cases.Check timing on the SPA, i usually see issue of timming, the var is fullfilled after the hit is send, this happens for example with some jQuery function and Angular Ajax.

Comment: The code is absolutely correct, the only problem I feel might be in your pagePath variable. Can you show how are you populating the `pagePath` variable

Comment: Thanks all for your thoughts! I'll have to dig deeper. In the meantime, I saw that it is only in a fraction of cases (~5%) that GA gets a (not set). So it seems a bit non-deterministic. The pagePath looks fine because it is the central variable that my entire app depends on. Let me research some more and I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ga('send', 'pageview', 'page path');
```

There is a alternative method using GTM , where you can easily (!!) set-up virtual pageviews, more info on this [link](http://www.lunametrics.com/blog/2014/09/10/fire-virtual-pageview-google-tag-manager/)

EDIT:
This is an example of one of my sites where i set the fields for a Virtual Pageview in GTM
[image: Link]

Comment: The documentation linked above says: "While technically the send command for pageview hits accepts an optional page field as the third parameter, passing the page field that way is not recommended when tracking single page applications. This is because fields passed via the send command are not set on the tracker—they apply to the current hit only." - it seems to discourage the code you suggest. Does it not?

Comment: That's why I suggested using Google Tag Manager, we run a single page service site here at work, and everything is fired as an event and consumed by GTM to send a Pageview Tag, that way funnels can be realised in Analytics.

Comment: Plus Google Tag Manager makes it easier as nothing needs to be redeployed most of the time

Comment: I don't get how GTM works in general. Do those "virtual pageviews" get analysed and reported exactly like standard ones in all the standard GA screens? Or do I have to reconfigure everything? I have a ten year history with my app on analytics...

Comment: Yes you emulate a pageview , what I do , but that's my own logic, is add a "/virtual/" prefix in the path. So i know the difference..

Basicly you define a trigger (a click, another event,...) which fires a Universal Analytics PageView tag, in that tag you can set all necassary fields.

For Analytics, it's all the same.

Comment: With the google measurement protocol you can even send a pageview using a POST http method. That is the underlying way of everything by the way. So like I said GA does not know the difference, it's all pageviews :) pageviews everywhere

Comment: @SwissMister did this help you out?

Comment: thank you so much - I am sorry I'll have to dive into this sometime later this week. I'll get back to you then.

Answer (score 0):

for the single page web application you should have to apply the GA where the change of `Route` or `hash` occurs.

And there you should have to include following line of code in without removing the previously written code on the one time loaded page:

`window.ga('send', 'pageview', location.hash);`

Comment: I have never used GTM. I have suggested you the solution which worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**for SPA Solution,**
you could try this one

```
ga('set', 'page', '/new-page.html');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/single-page-applications